# How to select the default worksheet from an excel file

Tags: excel, oledb

In the case where my user uploads an excel file with only one worksheet, I want to intelligently use only that worksheet.  However, when I pull the schema for this file I see an unexpected worksheet (circled):

[image: Unexpected worksheet in an excel schema]

The schema is retrieved via:

```
OleDBConnection.GetSchema("Tables")
```

In this case, it looks like the second worksheet is a filter defined by the user to "peg" two columns from scrolling.

**Question**: Is it safe for me to ignore worksheets with "$<filter>" appended?  Put another way, if I run through all the worksheets, throwing out the "$<filter>" types, and find that there is only one left, is it a reasonable default to use that worksheet?  Does anyone have a reference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, i would have thought so. $ usually means it is refering to named range or macro in that workbook. you might use Regex and capture anything within ' '.

Here is a reference on how to select data from a named range:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971514.aspx

How do u pull the schema for this file?  maybe you can filter it so that it only has Worksheets ?

Comment: I edited this answer with an MSDN reference so I can give you credit.  See my revised question regarding how I retrieve the schema.